# Unresolved reference Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE

Tags: android-permissions

I have an android mobile application, where I am trying to build in direct call feature. I have added the required permission request in the Manifest file. But in the function where I am trying to make the call, there is an error that says Unresolved reference: CALL_PHONE.

Here is my private function:

```
private fun callPhone(patientTelephone: String?) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
            REQUESTCALL)
    }else {
        val intentCall = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_CALL,
            Uri.fromParts(
                "tel",
                patientTelephone,
                null
            )
        )
        startActivity(intentCall)
    }
}
```

The request for permission in the manifest file is this:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

targetSdkVersion 33

Comment: Are you sure `Manifest` is resolving to the correct type `android.Manifest`?

Comment: Would you want me to share/check anything for that

Comment: Oh Yes you are correct. I have got this working. Please post your solution so that I can accept it as the correct answer. Changing Manifest to android.Manifest solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

import `android.Manifest` to your class it will resolve.

Comment: But why the IDE doesn't import it automatically?